# Read data in JSON format asp.net View in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I wonder what I'm doing wrong, already tested several tutorials without success, the data comes without the formatting that is in the script, in this example I have in my Controller,

```
public JsonResult GetDados()
{
    List<Object> resultado = new List<object>();
    resultado.Add(new
    {
        Nome = "studying Json",
        URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    });
    resultado.Add(new
    {
        Nome = "Json ",
        URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    });
    resultado.Add(new
    {
        Nome = "Mr. Json",
        URL = https://stackoverflow.com/"
    });
    return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View :

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetDados",
            success: function (dados) {
                $(dados).each(function (i) {
                    document.writeln("<p>Nome: " + dados[i].Nome + " | URL: " + dados[i].URL + "</p>")
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The correct display of the result would be:

Nome: studying Json | Url: https://stackoverflow.com/

Nome: Json | Url: https://stackoverflow.com/

Nome: Mr. Json | Url: https://stackoverflow.com/

I have this result
see that in document.writeln script, I'm writing the return json with a

, the image the result is not the same.

[image]

Comment: What formatting are you referring to? And if your wanting to create links, then your `dados[i].URL` value needs to be in a `<a>` element

Comment: Problem description could use some clarification , it's not very clear. Should not be using `document.write` after page loads...it will wipe whole page out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are calling "GetDados" directly from URL, which is why its not executing your view.

Try this..

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

View "index" :

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetDados",
            success: function (dados) {
                $(dados).each(function (i) {
                    document.writeln("<p>Nome: " + dados[i].Nome + " | URL: " + dados[i].URL + "</p>")
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```